# Is it possible to flip between a large block of C++ macros?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Assume I have a bunch of macros defining some variables - they need to be defined two ways in different parts of the code (yes, it's a bad idea, but refactoring will take a good long ways).

Is it possible to get the below snippet to work, that is, to print out 4 then 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#define ENABLE
#ifdef ENABLE
#define B 4
#define C 5
//imagine a bunch more here
#else
#define B 1
#define C 2
//imagine a bunch more here
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
#pragma push_macro("ENABLE")
#undef ENABLE
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
#pragma pop_macro("ENABLE")

    return 0;
}
```

It's certainly possible to achieve the same effect by defining B specifically, but if I have a large block of macros, that's not 100% practical:

```
#include <iostream>
#define B 4

int main()
{
#pragma push_macro("B")
#undef B
#define B 1
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
#pragma pop_macro("B")
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to set enable as a command line flag and then you can just compile with and without the flag.

Comment: It's in the same project. That's the awful part. Both blocks are live code in any given compilation, they're just defined differently in different areas.

Comment: @Carbon It seems that you should replace both of those macro blocks with appropriate alternatives.

Comment: I agree and do not like this at all

Comment: And yet here we are

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be able to do it by repeatedly `#include`ing a header file:

Header:

```
// Note: no inclusion guards!
#undef B
#undef C
#ifdef ENABLE
#define B 4
#define C 5
//imagine a bunch more here
#else
#define B 1
#define C 2
//imagine a bunch more here
#endif
```

Usage in a src file:

```
int main()
{
#define ENABLE
#include "header"
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
#undef ENABLE
#include "header"
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now that is a nifty trick! Until this mess gets excised, I'll be using it. Thanks man.

Comment: This is almost as bad as the time I followed instructions on the Internet and fixed a broken `.so` file with `sed`.

Comment: @Omnifarious Bad SONAME or something?

Comment: @DanielH - no, changing an embedded string. Near as I can tell it was to force lookup of broken capability in another program to fail so there would be no attempt to use the broken capability.